# does jade support conditional comments or not?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, templating

I've read two opposite things. One say yes and one say no. On their each site it works according to what they say. I want to know what's going on. Has the support been removed in updated version or am I missing something?

Site #1 - Official site "NO": http://jade-lang.com/reference/comments/

Site #2 - Respectable site "YES": http://www.learnjade.com/tour/comments/

Comment: It support conditional comment.

Comment: then why does on offical site it says no

Comment: I read that too on offficial site, but I used conditional comment and it worked for me. Try to add, see if it works for you.

Comment: i did, it didn't work. Official site is #1 right?. I typed this `//if lt IE 8
  \n script(src="/ie-sucks.js")` ...it just became this: `<!--if lt IE 8 \n script(src="/ie-sucks.js")
-->` and not this instead `<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="/ie-sucks.js"></script><![endif]-->`   "\n" is meant to show new line here

Comment: Jade website says "Jade does not have any special syntax for conditional comments." This doesn't mean you *can't* use conditional comments, rather you have to still use the regular syntax. See the last example on the page you referenced.

Comment: yes that what i was saying. Weird though that one version latest version doesn't and previous versions do. Personally this is no problem to me. I was thinking it's weird what could be the reason.